# Compilers: How to parse function calls and function definitions

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, interpreter, frontend

Upfront, I'm making an interpreter in Python, not an actual compiler that compiles to machine code. I've been skimming quite a few compiler construction guides lately and I understand the basics of generating tokens for your parser and building a syntax tree to evaluate arithmetic expressions, but I don't quite understand how to parse expressions with function calls inside them, things like

Fig. (a)

```
1 + pow(1, 1)
```

or how to parse lines when the user is defining a function like this

Fig. (b)

```
function newFunction( someArgs ){
   ... some magic ...
}
```

In Fig. (a), how should I tokenize this expression? After reading the reserved word "pow" should I grab everything up to the closing parenthesis and pass that to a parser? or should I include "pow", "(", "1", "1", and ")" each as seperate tokens and add them to my parse tree?

In Fib. (b) I don't have any idea where to even start when it comes to compiling function definitions. Any information to put me in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I'm using a Backus-Naur form grammar:

> S ::= expression
>
> expression ::= term | term ([+-] term)+
>
> term ::= factor | factor ([*/] factor)+
>
> factor ::= number | ( expression )
>
> number ::= [0-9]+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully there are going to be a few good anaswers to this quesiton, but the first things I'd advice you to do to help improve the quality of the questionare:

1. Limit your scope for your language and
2. Define your grammar.

Look into [Backus–Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), and learn about how to define the grammar your language is going to support.

In the first instance, look at writing a simple parser for a handful of mathematic functions to get your head around it.

```
<digit>   ::= "0"|"1"|...|"9"
<integer> ::= <digit>*
<expr>    ::= <integer> | <add> | <pow>
<add>     ::= "add(" <expr> "," <expr> ")"
<sub>     ::= "sub(" <expr> "," <expr> ")"
<pow>     ::= "pow(" <expr> "," <expr> ")"
```

From a formal grammar like this you can then have some surety around what is or isn't a valid expression.

For example: `add(1,2)` and `pow(2,add(2,1))` are both valid where as `add(1)` isn't as the `add` grammar needs two expressions.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe it never occurred to me to add the reserved words to my grammar. Let's say I did this for all predefined functions in my program, by which I mean adding them to my grammar table so that they can be recursively defined. How would I go about adding function definitions that the programmer using my language creates? should I dynamically add those to my grammar somehow or store them somewhere else?

Comment: In most languages, a function essentially is a pointer to a sequential list of statements/expressions.  How you manage this is up to you.  The simplest might be to store the name of the function in a symbol table as a pointer to this list, with your interpreter knowing to execute the list of instructions when a token with that id is found in the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Another poster suggests adding the names of functions to your grammar.

That works for toy languages, but not for practical ones where there may be huge libraries as well as large sets of user defined functions.

You can handle the latter by adding function calls to the BNF,
in a way that leaves the function name out of the grammar:

```
S ::= expression

expression ::= term | term ([+-] term)+

term ::= factor | factor ([*/] factor)+

factor ::= number | ( expression ) | identifier |  functioncall

functioncall ::= identifier [(]  arguments [)]

arguments ::= empty | arguments 

arguments ::= expression |  arguments [,] expression

number ::= [0-9]+

identifier ::= [a-z]+
```

Now your parser can pick up function calls.  (Left out of the grammer is a way to *define* functions... but that's just more syntax which I leave it for you to add).

The price for this is that after parsing, something has decide for each function name, precisely which bit of code it represents.  You will need a symbol table to do this.
That's another question.

Comment: What about function calls such as `list_of_funcs[0]()`?

Comment: If you allow a special expression to compute the function to be called, then you modify the grammar accordingly.   To handle your specific example first you need to extend the definition of factor as factor = ... | factor '[' expression ']' ;   Then you change fuctioncall:   functioncall = factor '[' arguments ']'.    BNF is pretty expressive.